# Migrating from existing legacy Knowledge base to Salesforce Knowledge base

Tags: data-loader, knowledge, migration, servicecloud, data-migration

Our organisation has decided to move from legacy knowledge base system to Salesforce Knowledge base.

We have huge KB and bunch of files (doc, pdf).

One of the solution is to move from existing KB is, preparing CSV and documents and do the upload. This process is time consuming and have manual effort as well.

Is there any other **solution**, **best practices** or **tool** to make the process efficient? Any step we could automate. We are open for both **paid** and free (better) solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I personally use SSIS and KingswaySoft SF Connector.    We migrated 20+ million records of data (including PDF and other attachments).   It's pretty intuitive and great for designing/testing the migration to a sandbox -- it's similiar to Data Loader UI.  Once you're ready to mke the move to production, you need only to change the login credentials to salesforce.   I believe it's about $1,000/year/license and you may need 2  if your company requires you also build your SSIS on a Test server.

https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-salesforce